# How to use Spring Boot externalized configuration at Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

For externalizing configuration in a spring Boot application, I follow [the standard way](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) of having an `application.properties` in the classpath. And then, in the production environment, I put another `application.properties` beside the JAR which overrides the earlier one. This way, I can have, say, a `name` property having different values in development and production environments.

Liked to know how to do the same thing when deploying to Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply put the properties to override as environment variables (replace dots with underscores, and Boot will match everything up).

Comment: Thank you! And, the way to put environment variables, as I see in CF docs, should be through manifest.yml -> http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block , I think.

Comment: I don't use the manifest. I configure the application instance directly using the CLI or Web interface (since different instances of the same application have different settings).

Comment: Great! Tested it to be working perfectly. (Created the environment variable using the web interface)

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to have a look into the [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config) Spring project within [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/):

"Centralized external configuration management backed by a git repository. The configuration resources map directly to Spring `Environment` but could be used by non-Spring applications if desired."